# Beginner Java Counter code

Tags: java, homework, beginner

My professor wants me to do this:

> Write a number of interchangeable counters using the Counter interface below:

```
public interface Counter {
/** Current value of this counter. */
int value();
/** Increment this counter. */
void up();
/** Decrement this counter. */
void down();
}
```

I need comments on my work so far.  Do you think it's sufficient?  How do I work on the ResetableCounter?  I'm very new to Java and it's been a long time since I've done C++.

Develop the following:

> An interface ResetableCounter that supports the message void reset() in addition to those of Counter.

Here's what I did:

```
public interface ResetableCounter {
void reset();
int value();
void up();
void down();
}
```

> An implementation of ResetableCounter called BasicCounter that starts at the value 0 and counts up and down by +1 and -1 respectively.

Here's what I did:

```
public class BasicCounter implements ResetableCounter
    {
      int counterVariable = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BasicCounter cnt = new BasicCounter();
        cnt.up();
        cnt.down();
        System.out.printf("The value is %d", cnt.counterVariable); 
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.counterVariable = 0;
    }

    public int value() {
        return this.counterVariable;
    }

    public void up() {
        ++this.counterVariable;
    }

    public void down() {
        --this.counterVariable;
    }
    }
```

> An implementation of ResetableCounter called SquareCounter that starts at the value 2, counts up by squaring its current value, and counts down by taking the square root of its current value (always rounding up, i.e. 1.7 is rounded to 2, just like 1.2 is rounded to 2).

Here's what I did:

```
public class SquareCounter implements ResetableCounter {
int counterVariable = 2;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SquareCounter cnt = new SquareCounter();
    cnt.up();
    cnt.down();
    double d = Math.ceil(cnt.counterVariable);
    System.out.printf("The value is %f", d); 
}

public void reset() {
    this.counterVariable = 0;
}

public int value() {
    return this.counterVariable;
}

public void up() {
    Math.pow(this.counterVariable, 2);
}

public void down() {
    Math.sqrt(this.counterVariable);
} 
 }
```

> An implementation of ResetableCounter called FlexibleCounter that allows clients to specify a start value as well as an additive increment (used for counting up) when a counter is created. For example new FlexibleCounter(-10, 3) would yield a counter with the current value -10; after a call to up() its value would be -7.

```
public class FlexibleCounter implements ResetableCounter
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int start = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int step = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    start.up();
    System.out.printf("The value is %d", count); 
}

public void reset() {
    this.count = 0;
}

public int value() {
    return this.count;
}

public void up() {
    this.count = args[0] + args[1];
}

public void down() {
    --this.count;
}
}
```

> All of your implementations should be resetable, and each should contain a main method that tests whether the implementation works as expected using assert as we did in lecture (this is a simple approach to unit testing which we'll talk about more later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BasicCounter` is impeccable.  (The indentation of the braces is a bit off, but maybe that's an artifact from pasting into this site.)  I would suggest renaming `counterVariable` to just `count`, since it would be silly to name everything `fooVariable` and `barVariable`.

Your `SquareCounter` is buggy.  Think about what its `reset()` should do.  (Hint: it would be a good idea for the `SquareCounter()` constructor to call `reset()`.)  Also, in `up()` and `down()`, how is `counterVariable` being modified?  (Hint: right now, it *isn't* being modified.)  Note that `Math.pow()` and `Math.sqrt()` return `double` rather than `int`, so you'll have to cast to `int` at some point.

Unfortunately, by the rules of this website, we only improve code that has already been written.  Therefore, I'll decline to comment on `FlexibleCounter` until you present something that at least compiles.

Comment: public class FlexibleCounter implements ResetableCounter
    {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int start = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  int step = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  start.up();
  System.out.printf("The value is %d", count); 
 }
 
 public void reset() {
  this.count = 0;
 }

 public int value() {
  return this.count;
 }

 public void up() {
  this.count = args[0] + args[1];
 }

 public void down() {
  --this.count;
 }
    }

Comment: what do you think of the FlexibleCounter I just added?

Comment: It matters not what I think. The compiler doesn't like it.

Comment: I know. How do I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, that's out of scope for this website, where we only improve working code. We also don't hand out homework answers. I'm going to end this discussion on the following two hints. 1) `start` is an `int`; you can't call `.up()` on it. *Should you construct an object?* 2) `args` is not available within the scope of the `up()` method. *What instance variables should you use instead?*

Answer (score 2):

> An interface ResetableCounter that supports the message void reset() in **addition to those of Counter**.

Your professor provides this statement to you as a *hint*. It is practically saying `ResetableCounter` should `extends` `Counter` interface.

make `countVariable` or `count`(as @200_success suggested) **private**. As no other outside class should have any permission to change the count.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest three changes:

- All the advanced counter classes, `SquareCounter`, `FlexibleCount`, `ResettableCounter` should extend the Counter interface.
- Do not add the `main()` method inside the counters. Instead , have a
  seperate class say `Driver` which creates and calls methods on the
  counters.
- The counter variable should be private.
- In your `MathCounter`, when calling `Math.pow()` or `Math.sqrt()` , please
  assign these value to the counter variable. E.g: `counter= Math.pow();`
- e. In your flexible  counter down instead of using `--counter`, you
  should be doing : `counter=counter-step`